# Android ArCore in emulator issue

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have an issue in Android emulator (I use Google Pixel 2 with Google APIs). When I open AR fragment I receive next issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/ar/core/h;
    at com.google.ar.core.ArCoreApk.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
```

No results found on Google so asking here. I've installed ArCore apk for emulator through adb. No clues what's going on...

Comment: Is your emulator 27.2.9 or later ?  Probably you have looked into but i am adding link that shows instructions for the emulator. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator

Comment: It is 28 version. Same issue appears on the real device (samsung S8). Sceneform tells that it will download ArCore apk by default but I am not getting that dialog.

Comment: If you use fragment yeah it automatically shows a dialog for installing arcore apk.

Comment: Other issue I get during install apk: Error: Class content provided for type descriptor com.google.ar.core.h actually defines class com.google.ar.core.H

Comment: Did you download the ARCore for Emulator App and dropped in your emulator?

Comment: @Array I am getting the say error when trying to install the app with the arcore. I seems that it is an issue when you use `arcore` along with `firebase-perf`. Did you find any solutions for your case?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

So the issue appears only on `com.google.ar:core:1.4.0`, on `com.google.ar:core:1.3.0` it is not reproducible. I will create an issue on ArCore SDK page on Github.

When I switched to ArCore version 1.3.0 (both Sceneform and ArCore) - all started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this line in your Manifest:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>`

and should use the ArFragment in your layout xml:

```
<fragment android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
  android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This should be enough for the app check all the needs and open dialog to install.

Just remember that for emulator you can download "**ARCore for Emulator**", on this guide [Run AR Apps in Android Emulator](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator) you have the [releases](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases) for the apk, download and drop on the emulator to install

Comment: That's not actually correct. I want ARCore to be optional and it did work after I downgraded the ARCore itself. I did upload ARCore apk on emulator and I also did normal run on real device (see comment mentioning Samsung S8). All other things that you have mentioned are present in the project but with optional configuration and now it work.

Comment: This is not a proper solution to it. I feel there is some problem in synching part of 'com.google.ar:core:1.4.0'